# How to wrap code containing regex into a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have data such as this:

```
data_in <- read_table2("ID  Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4 Q26_2_1 Q26_2_2 Q26_2_3 Q26_2_4 Q26_3_1 Q26_3_2 Q26_3_3 Q26_3_4 Q26_4_1 Q26_4_2 Q26_4_3 Q26_4_4 Q26_5_1 Q26_5_2 Q26_5_3 Q26_5_4 Q14_1_1 Q14_1_2 Q14_1_3 Q14_1_4 Q14_1_5 Q14_1_6 Q14_2_1 Q14_2_2 Q14_2_3 Q14_2_4 Q14_2_5 Q14_2_6 Q14_3_1 Q14_3_2 Q14_3_3 Q14_3_4 Q14_3_5 Q14_3_6 Q14_4_1 Q14_4_2 Q14_4_3 Q14_4_4 Q14_4_5 Q14_4_6 Q14_5_1 Q14_5_2 Q14_5_3 Q14_5_4 Q14_5_5 Q14_5_6
1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   1   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
3   1   NA  1   NA  1   NA  1   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   1   1   1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  1   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA
4   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
5   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  1   1   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  1   1   1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA
")
```

I would like to manipulate the data as so: if the sum of series of questions is equal to 0, then assign missing to that entire series, if it is not equal to 0, then assign "0". I have already written the code to manipulate this data.

The problem is that I have many series of questions, and I would like to write this into a function, so that I can apply it to each question series, so I don't need to keep copy pasting like this:

```
data_out <- 
data_in  %>%
  
  ### Q26 ####
  # Convert the Q26 series missing to zero
  mutate(across(matches("Q26"), ~replace_na(., 0))) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric) %>%
  
  # Q26_1 
  mutate(sum_Q26_1=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q26_1_[1-4]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q26_1_[1-4]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q26_1==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>%
  
  # Q26_2 
  mutate(sum_Q26_2=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q26_2_[1-4]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q26_2_[1-4]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q26_2==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>%
  
  # Q26_3 
  mutate(sum_Q26_3=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q26_3_[1-4]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q26_3_[1-4]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q26_3==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>% 
  
  # Q26_4
  mutate(sum_Q26_4=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q26_4_[1-4]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q26_4_[1-4]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q26_4==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>%
  
  
  # Q26_5
  mutate(sum_Q26_5=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q26_5_[1-4]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q26_5_[1-4]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q26_5==0~"NA",
      
                                                  TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>% 
  
  
  ### Q14 ####
  mutate(across(matches("Q14"), ~replace_na(., 0))) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric) %>%
  
  # Q14_1 
  mutate(sum_Q14_1=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q14_1_[1-6]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q14_1_[1-6]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q14_1==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>%
  
  # Q14_2 
  mutate(sum_Q14_2=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q14_2_[1-6]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q14_2_[1-6]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q14_2==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>%
  
  # Q14_3 
  mutate(sum_Q14_3=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q14_3_[1-6]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q14_3_[1-6]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q14_3==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>% 
  
  # Q14_4
  mutate(sum_Q14_4=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q14_4_[1-6]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q14_4_[1-6]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q14_4==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.)))) %>%
  
  
  # Q14_5
  mutate(sum_Q14_5=rowSums(select(.,matches(("^Q14_5_[1-6]$"))), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^Q14_5_[1-6]$"),.fns=~case_when(sum_Q14_5==0~"NA",
                                                         TRUE~as.character(.))))
```

Notice that the regex pattern changes over the questions. For example:
Q26 series is **matches(("^Q26_1_[1-4]$")))**

whereas,
Q14 series is **matches(("^Q14_1_[1-6]$")))**

I don't know to wrap this into a function given the changing regex patterns. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my observation, I assume that

1. those `sum_...` columns are just temporary variables, and I can freely drop them if I want;
2. although you did another `mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)` later in your pipeline, you actually want each column `as.character` and only contains `"0"`, `"1"` or `NA`;
3. in lines like this `sum_Q14_4==0~"NA"`, you intend to assign it a missing value of a character type (which should be `NA_character_`), not an `"NA"` literal.

Then, your code simplifies to:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_in %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("qns", "sub1", "sub2"), names_pattern = "([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)") %>% 
  group_by(ID, qns, sub1) %>% 
  mutate(value = if (all(is.na(value))) NA_character_ else replace_na(value, "0")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("qns", "sub1", "sub2"))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 51
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4 Q26_2_1 Q26_2_2 Q26_2_3 Q26_2_4 Q26_3_1 Q26_3_2 Q26_3_3 Q26_3_4 Q26_4_1 Q26_4_2 Q26_4_3 Q26_4_4 Q26_5_1 Q26_5_2
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
2     2 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
3     3 1       0       1       0       1       0       1       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1      
4     4 0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0      
5     5 1       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       1      
# ... with 32 more variables: Q26_5_3 <chr>, Q26_5_4 <chr>, Q14_1_1 <chr>, Q14_1_2 <chr>, Q14_1_3 <chr>, Q14_1_4 <chr>, Q14_1_5 <chr>, Q14_1_6 <chr>,
#   Q14_2_1 <chr>, Q14_2_2 <chr>, Q14_2_3 <chr>, Q14_2_4 <chr>, Q14_2_5 <chr>, Q14_2_6 <chr>, Q14_3_1 <chr>, Q14_3_2 <chr>, Q14_3_3 <chr>,
#   Q14_3_4 <chr>, Q14_3_5 <chr>, Q14_3_6 <chr>, Q14_4_1 <chr>, Q14_4_2 <chr>, Q14_4_3 <chr>, Q14_4_4 <chr>, Q14_4_5 <chr>, Q14_4_6 <chr>,
#   Q14_5_1 <chr>, Q14_5_2 <chr>, Q14_5_3 <chr>, Q14_5_4 <chr>, Q14_5_5 <chr>, Q14_5_6 <chr>
```

**Update**

Since you only want to apply this logic to `Q26` and `Q14`, then you can try the code below, which allows you to change only a subset of the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

only_at <- function(df, ..., join_by, .do) {
  order <- names(df)
  cols_to_change <- select(df, !!join_by, ...)
  cols_to_keep <- select(df, !!join_by, !any_of(names(cols_to_change)))
  left_join(.do(cols_to_change), cols_to_keep, join_by)[, order]
}

data_in %>% 
  only_at(ID, starts_with("Q26"), starts_with("Q14"), 
    join_by = "ID", 
    .do = . %>% 
      pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("qns", "sub1", "sub2"), names_pattern = "([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)") %>% 
      group_by(ID, qns, sub1) %>% 
      mutate(value = if (all(is.na(value))) NA_character_ else replace_na(value, "0")) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = c("qns", "sub1", "sub2"))
  )
```

Test data look like this

```
> data_in
# A tibble: 5 x 53
     ID random_column Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4 Q26_2_1 Q26_2_2 random_column2 Q26_2_3 Q26_2_4 Q26_3_1 Q26_3_2 Q26_3_3 Q26_3_4 Q26_4_1 Q26_4_2
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>   <lgl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1 NA                 NA NA           NA      NA      NA      NA two                 NA      NA      NA NA      NA           NA      NA NA     
2     2 orange             NA NA           NA      NA      NA      NA one                 NA      NA      NA NA      NA           NA      NA NA     
3     3 NA                  1 NA            1      NA       1      NA NA                   1      NA       1 NA      NA           NA      NA NA     
4     4 apple              NA NA           NA       1      NA      NA one                 NA       1      NA NA      NA            1      NA NA     
5     5 orange              1 NA           NA      NA      NA       1 NA                   1      NA       1 NA      NA           NA       1 NA     
# ... with 36 more variables: Q26_4_3 <lgl>, Q26_4_4 <dbl>, Q26_5_1 <dbl>, Q26_5_2 <dbl>, Q26_5_3 <dbl>, Q26_5_4 <dbl>, Q14_1_1 <lgl>, Q14_1_2 <lgl>,
#   Q14_1_3 <dbl>, Q14_1_4 <lgl>, Q14_1_5 <lgl>, Q14_1_6 <dbl>, Q14_2_1 <lgl>, Q14_2_2 <lgl>, Q14_2_3 <dbl>, Q14_2_4 <lgl>, Q14_2_5 <lgl>,
#   Q14_2_6 <dbl>, Q14_3_1 <dbl>, Q14_3_2 <dbl>, Q14_3_3 <dbl>, Q14_3_4 <lgl>, Q14_3_5 <lgl>, Q14_3_6 <dbl>, Q14_4_1 <lgl>, Q14_4_2 <lgl>,
#   Q14_4_3 <dbl>, Q14_4_4 <lgl>, Q14_4_5 <lgl>, Q14_4_6 <dbl>, Q14_5_1 <lgl>, Q14_5_2 <lgl>, Q14_5_3 <dbl>, Q14_5_4 <lgl>, Q14_5_5 <lgl>, Q14_5_6 <dbl>
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 53
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID random_column Q26_1_1 Q26_1_2 Q26_1_3 Q26_1_4 Q26_2_1 Q26_2_2 random_column2 Q26_2_3 Q26_2_4 Q26_3_1 Q26_3_2 Q26_3_3 Q26_3_4 Q26_4_1 Q26_4_2
  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>          <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 NA            NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      two            NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
2     2 orange        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      one            NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
3     3 NA            1       0       1       0       1       0       NA             1       0       1       0       0       0       0       0      
4     4 apple         0       0       0       1       0       0       one            0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0      
5     5 orange        1       0       0       0       0       1       NA             1       0       1       0       0       0       1       0      
# ... with 36 more variables: Q26_4_3 <chr>, Q26_4_4 <chr>, Q26_5_1 <chr>, Q26_5_2 <chr>, Q26_5_3 <chr>, Q26_5_4 <chr>, Q14_1_1 <chr>, Q14_1_2 <chr>,
#   Q14_1_3 <chr>, Q14_1_4 <chr>, Q14_1_5 <chr>, Q14_1_6 <chr>, Q14_2_1 <chr>, Q14_2_2 <chr>, Q14_2_3 <chr>, Q14_2_4 <chr>, Q14_2_5 <chr>,
#   Q14_2_6 <chr>, Q14_3_1 <chr>, Q14_3_2 <chr>, Q14_3_3 <chr>, Q14_3_4 <chr>, Q14_3_5 <chr>, Q14_3_6 <chr>, Q14_4_1 <chr>, Q14_4_2 <chr>,
#   Q14_4_3 <chr>, Q14_4_4 <chr>, Q14_4_5 <chr>, Q14_4_6 <chr>, Q14_5_1 <chr>, Q14_5_2 <chr>, Q14_5_3 <chr>, Q14_5_4 <chr>, Q14_5_5 <chr>, Q14_5_6 <chr>
```

Test data

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), random_column = c(NA, "orange", 
NA, "apple", "orange"), Q26_1_1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q26_1_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q26_1_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), Q26_1_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA), Q26_2_1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), Q26_2_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1), random_column2 = c("two", "one", NA, "one", NA
), Q26_2_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q26_2_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA), Q26_3_1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q26_3_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Q26_3_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q26_3_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA), Q26_4_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), Q26_4_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Q26_4_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q26_4_4 = c(NA, NA, 
1, 1, NA), Q26_5_1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q26_5_2 = c(NA, NA, 
1, NA, 1), Q26_5_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q26_5_4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 1, NA), Q14_1_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_1_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_1_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q14_1_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_1_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_1_6 = c(1, 
1, NA, 1, NA), Q14_2_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_2_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_2_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q14_2_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_2_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_2_6 = c(1, 
1, NA, 1, NA), Q14_3_1 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_3_2 = c(1, 
NA, 1, NA, NA), Q14_3_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q14_3_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_3_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_3_6 = c(NA, 
1, NA, 1, NA), Q14_4_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_4_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_4_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), Q14_4_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_4_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_4_6 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, NA), Q14_5_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_5_2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_5_3 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Q14_5_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_5_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q14_5_6 = c(1, 
1, NA, 1, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Some Explanations about `!!join_by` and `.do = . %>% ...`

Simply speaking, `!!` is a special operator used in the `<tidy-select>` semantics. It forces the evaluation of `join_by`. In other words, it tells the `select` function that `join_by` is not a variable in the dataframe. For more comprehensive explanations, see this [R-blog](https://www.r-%20bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/).

`.do` is an argument that takes a function as its input. Nothing special with the name. You can also call it `dosomthing` or `whatever_you_like`. The key here is this part:

```
. %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("qns", "sub1", "sub2"), names_pattern = "([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)") %>% 
  group_by(ID, qns, sub1) %>% 
  mutate(value = if (all(is.na(value))) NA_character_ else replace_na(value, "0")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("qns", "sub1", "sub2"))
```

When a pipeline starts with a `.`, the whole pipeline will be converted into a single function. So the `.do = . %>% ...` is just passing a function to the `.do` argument. You can try typing `. %>% + 1` in R console and see what it returns. For more information, see `` ?`%>%` ``

Comment: I do not want to convert all the NAs in the survey to 0, only a subset of them. Also, I have many different types of questions in this survey (up to 600 questions) -- so your solution does not work. Any suggestions for making that function?

Comment: @NewBee So you want a function that only modifies Q26 and Q14 and keeps all other questions unchanged?

Comment: I have about 10 series of these questions so ideally the function will only change Q26 and then I can use that function to change Q14 and all the other questions that are like it

Comment: this is cool, do you mind explaining what this does ".do = . %>%" ? and the !!join_by?

Comment: one more thing, the format of some of the columns is Q67_1_2_TEXT. Do you mind adjusting the names patterns in your solution? I'm still trying to figure out regex :(

Comment: I tried ([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+), but it throws an Error: `regex` should define 3 groups;  found.

Comment: @NewBee I will write a short explanation about those two things later. Let's address your `regex` problem first. If there is a variable like this `Q67_1_2_TEXT`, will there be another column just named as`Q67_1_2` without the `_TEXT` suffix?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to add "sub3" for that "TEXT". Thanks!